# Azure function alerts/health check

Tags: c#, azure, function, alerts, health-check

I dont have any code to show. I am new to azure and would like to know how to create a health check for an azure function. I know I can use application insights but i'm am being requested to use an alert to know if I have an issue. I have read and found out that in order to get an alert I need to have health check on my function. I understand that I need a path for the health check but dont know where to start.

Comment: How is your azure function triggered?

Comment: Http trigger and a timer

Comment: Since an azure function does not run continuously I wonder what the point of a regular health check is. I suppose it might be better to create an alert when the function execution fails

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide range of alerts that can be triggered by your function. You can activate the functionality by:

**Open your function app and navigate to alerts**:

[image]

**Then you can create an alert rule. Select your signal**:

[image]

Once you have selected your signal, move on to actions where you can either:

1. Select an existing action group,
2. Create a new action group.

An [action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups) determines who will be notified by the alerts etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. The alert I am trying to create is for health check status. I applied the alert but I get no alert. I read that with app functions you have to set up a path under health checks. Is this true? And if so which path do I use or how does that work?